# Inserting a list as fact in statelessKieSession in drools

Tags: java, drools

I am trying to insert a list as a fact in kieSession.what is the difference between the below two methods?.

Method1:

```
StatelessKieSession kieSession1 = kieBase.newStatelessKieSession();
            kieSession1.execute(List);
```

Method2:

```
StatefulKnowledgeSession kieSession = (StatefulKnowledgeSession) kieBase.newKieSession();
kieSession.insert(List);
            kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

I am able to iterate the list that is sent as parameter inside the drl in the stateful session, But i am not able to do that in stateless session. Can anyone tell how both sessions process the list passed as a fact?

Comment: Did you read the javadocs for `execute(Iterable x)` and `insert(Object y)`?

Comment: Yes.. execute inserts all the objects individually and then calls the fireAllRules.. But i want to use the list inside the drl and iterate the objects inside the drl.. How can i do it with a stateless session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StatelessKieSession kieSession1 = kieBase.newStatelessKieSession();
kieSession1.execute( (Object)aList );
```

Drools API Javadoc documents both overloaded forms of `execute` and explains what happens with either form.